# PHP Warning: Undefined array key 1 in PHP 8.0

Tags: php, arrays, key, undefined, warnings

The above warning appears in PHP 8.0, for the line of code below:

```
list( $delim, $page_index ) = explode( '/', $query_string['page'] );
```

Whole function as follows:

```
function wpsc_remove_page_from_query_string( $query_string ) {

if ( false === strpos( implode( ' ', $query_string ), 'wpsc' ) ) {
    return $query_string;
}

if ( isset( $query_string['name'] ) && $query_string['name'] == 'page' && isset( $query_string['page'] ) ) {
    unset( $query_string['name'] );

    list( $delim, $page_index ) = explode( '/', $query_string['page'] );

    $query_string['paged'] = $page_index;
}

if ( isset( $query_string['wpsc-product'] ) && 'page' == $query_string['wpsc-product'] ) {
    $query_string['wpsc-product'] = '';
}

if ( isset( $query_string['name'] ) && is_numeric( $query_string['name'] ) ) {
    $query_string['paged'] = $query_string['name'];
    $query_string['page']  = '/'.$query_string['name'];

    $query_string['posts_per_page'] = get_option('wpsc_products_per_page');
}

if ( isset( $query_string['wpsc-product'] ) && is_numeric( $query_string['wpsc-product'] ) ) {
    unset( $query_string['wpsc-product'] );
}

if ( isset( $query_string['wpsc_product_category'] ) && 'page' == $query_string['wpsc_product_category'] ) {
    unset( $query_string['wpsc_product_category'] );
}

if ( isset( $query_string['name'] ) && is_numeric( $query_string['name'] ) ) {
    unset( $query_string['name'] );
}

if ( isset($query_string['term']) && 'page' == $query_string['term'] )  {
    unset( $query_string['term'] );
    unset( $query_string['taxonomy'] );
}

return $query_string;
```

}

As still at very early stages of learning php, having difficulty in solving this one.
Would anyone know the best way of tweaking the above code for php 8 compatibility?

Comment: `[$delim, $page_index] = explode('/', $query_string['page']) + ['', 0];`?

Comment: This happens, when the explode will return an array, but has less than two elements as you decompose.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Have tried your suggestion Syscall. Will let you know if this works.

Comment: Hi Syscall. Just to let you know that your suggestion worked. I'm new to this site, so not sure how I can give you an upvote, or similar thing for your help? I know normally there's a tick you can tick to highlight when an answer, solves a question.